# Media queries not loading in small sizes

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

I have a client with a wordpress website who asked me to create some responsive landing pages. I'm having trouble with small media queries sizes, as I can manage to get working big sizes until 767px. If I try to add any css for sizes like 320, 480, etc, it gets ignored. Apparently, the installed theme (Spacious) uses Blueprint, but I really have no clue what I'm doing wrong :(

This is the landing page in question: http://blog.helpinwords.com/go/plantilla-1/

Fiddle in comments -

Thank you very much :(

Comment: its hard to tell whats wrong if you expect people to go over your site and look through your css and point out the buggy stuff; you should be able to identify the problem and narrow down the culprits; like you said somewhere between 768 and bellow somethings not working, well post that rest of the css thats not working in a jsfiddle or here and some markup to better illustrate your problem

Comment: Do you have accidentally activated the mobile version of Wordpress site?

Comment: Just checked and seems it's not activated. And here's all the code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2wxtjdn/ . My added classes are "primeracaja", "segundacaja" and "terceracaja"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, but I'm still in doubt: Apparently, I could only add my classes to 5 or so media query tags (even thought there are more applied to the theme). If I added any more, they got ignored.

Maybe is a theme or wordpress bug? I was only able to use the wordpress editor...